# Create water(fluid) surface with Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

How can i create water surface with **Sprite Kit**?

I have searched and found help for **Cocos2d** which uses **box2d** to create physics effects for water like object floating over water and some part of it in water and other outside of water. Objects going down the water with as force as applied to throw it into the water and similar effects.

So how can i achieve the same water effect with **Sprite Kit**? Any ideas

Answer (score 6):

The `SKPhysicsBody` class has properties called `linearDamping` and `angularDamping`, which you can modify to simulate liquid friction (fluid resistance) for objects thrown into the water. You can read up on these in the [SKPhysicsBody Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_15).